# MATLAB - Eigenvectors not displaying using the code null(A-[eigenvalue]*eye(n));

Tags: matlab

[Problem I'm attempting to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Qsh.png)

I just have to prove a matrix is diagonalizable. I've been following my book's steps for this, and need to create eigenvectors. Unfortunately, only one eigenvector is appearing, and I do not understand why. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxzIB.png) is my code. I do have commands to display each value. Can someone help me understand what to do here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Those numbers 5.2930 etc. are _approximations_ -- MATLAB is displaying only four decimal places. Try asking for e.g. `null(E-F(1)*eye(4))` instead of `null(E-5.293*eye(4))`.

Comment: (You're getting _one_ eigenvector rather than _none_ because it happens that one of the eigenvalues is exactly 2, so displaying it to 4 decimal places doesn't do any harm.)